# Add translation for model field using django rosetta

Tags: django, django-rosetta

I am using a models field contents to dynamically create a menu.  That's fine, but how can I ensure there is a translation for it?

Is it possible for the user to add a new translation through the admin interface or can I put something in the save method so the fields value is added to the .po file?

Comment: Check out http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: The users are already using rosetta for the rest of the translations so if I can't get rosetta to do it, I'll just create an addition field for the translation.  But thanks for the link, I'll keep that handy.